# Possible to validate ServiceStack's authentication cookie client side?

Tags: authentication, cookies, client, servicestack

I am having a HTML (Angular) site which has a login button and needs (of course) to present a different GUI when the user is authenticated. I am using ServiceStack based REST services. Now when a user is successfully authenticated I was wondering if it is possible to check the generated authentication cookie (by ServiceStack) on the client only. I just need to check the userid, maybe role and expiration date of the cookie. Advantage is I do not have to make  'CheckUserIsAuthenticated' server rest call's just for showing a different GUI (of source CRUD actions are validated serverside).

Answer (score 0):

You can check that a cookie exists with `document.cookie`, as it's hard to work with directly Mozilla provides a [lightweight cookies wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) to make it easier to work with, likewise AngularJS provides [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) provider.

But a cookie doesn't tell you anything about the user since even non-authenticated / anonymous users will have cookies. Instead to check if the user is authenticated you can call `/auth` route via ajax which when authenticated ServiceStack will return summary info about the user, e.g:

```
{

    UserId: "1",
    SessionId: "{sessionId}",
    UserName: "user@gmail.com",
    DisplayName: "First Last"
}
```

If the user is not authenticated `/auth` will return `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I now ended up with:

1. Login and authenticate on the server.
2. After successful authentication I store the needed information (name, email, timeout, role) using local storage.

This way I do not need to go to the server every time I need some simple GUI adjustments for my pages. From a security perspective this does not pose a real threat because in the end serious actions are always re-authenticated on the server.